# Tomcat cannot find my webapp

Tags: tomcat

I installed Tomcat 7 and checked that the following links work:

```
http://localhost:8080 
http://localhost:8080/docs
```

I put a file called "GeniusWeb.war" in "webapps", and opened the following link:

```
http://localhost:8080/GeniusWeb
```

I got an "404" error.

I looked at the webapps folder and saw that there is a new "GeniusWeb" folder, so the Tomcat server actually found the war file and expanded it, but, for some reason it does not find it when I go to the link.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server could not find what was requested. You need to add resource/page in newly created context. Create `index.jsp` and request it `http://localhost:8080/GeniusWeb` or `http://localhost:8080/GeniusWeb/file_or_resource.ext`

Comment: I already have an "index.jsp" file inside the webapps/GeniusWeb folder. It still replies with 404!

Comment: Context  and resource (pages) names are case-sensitive. If you  saved/created index.jsp using notepad then check its extension (index.jsp.txt). Always use "file.jsp" (double quote) to save a text document as jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `catalina.out` file present under `tomcat/logs` folder.
There you can find out what actually gone wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).